# Select option and radio; reflect selection in other

Tags: javascript, html

I have a map and using radio buttons I allow the user to select a point on the map, but they can also use the dropdown to select if they wish (which is easier on phones where the map is tiny).

How do I keep the radio and dropdown selection in sync so that when one is selected the other reflects the change?

Code for Setting up the radio buttons:

```
echo"<div class='site' style='margin:".$y."px 0px 0px ".$x."px;'>
    <input type='radio' id='site_".$site_id."' name='site_id'  value='".$site_id."' disabled/>
    <label for='site_".$site_id."'><span>".$site_id."</span></label>
    </div>";
```

For creating the option in dropdown

```
echo "<select id='site_select' name='site_select'>";
  foreach($avail_sites as $site){
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('site_".$site->id."').disabled=false;</script>";
    echo "<option value='".$site->id."'>Site: ".$site->name."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Post some code please, or maybe a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that will keep select and radio buttons in sync, based on common values. Probably best to change the first two selectors to be a bit more specific (use a class name, or something).

```
(function() {
    var sel = document.querySelector("select"),
    opts = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

    sel.addEventListener('change', function() {
       var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
       for(var i=0, max = opts.length; i<max; i++) {
           if (opts[i].value == val) {
               opts[i].checked = "checked";
           }
       }
    });

    for(var i=0, max = opts.length; i<max; i++) {
        opts[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            var val = this.value;
            for (var i=0, max=sel.options.length; i<max; i++) {
                if (sel.options[i].value == val) {
                   sel.options[i].selected = "selected";
                   return;
               }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/QCEbJ/